# Angular Use Promise in a Boolean function

Tags: angular, promise

I may not get the concept right about Promise() in Angular, but how should I modify below code so that checkExistence() can return a boolean?

```
public checkExistence(value: string): boolean{
  var exist = false;
  return this.getRefData().then((rec: string[]) => {
    return rec.some(el => {
        el === value;
    });
  });
}

private async getRefData() {
  return await this.configurationService.retrieveTableData().toPromise(); 
}
```

At this point, error is thrown in checkExistence(): `[ts] Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`

**EDIT**

Managed to get rid of above error by doing this:

```
public checkExistence(value: string): boolean{
  var exist = false;
  this.getRefData().then((rec: string[]) => {
    return rec.some(el => {
        return el === value;
    });
  });
}
```

Now the problem is that the function is actually not returning anything `[ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.` Why is it not returning anything?

Comment: your edit is not required. see my solution

Answer (score 2):

`checkExistence` returns is a promise which resolves to `boolean`

```
public checkExistence(value: string): Promise<boolean>{
  var exist = false;
  return this.getRefData().then((rec: string[]) => {
    return rec.some(el => {
        el === value;
    });
  });
}
```

To use check `checkExistence` elsewhere:

```
checkExistence()
   .then((value:boolean)=>{console.log(value)})
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to return a boolean only, not Promise<boolean> or anything else. Because checkExistence() will be used elsewhere as `if(checkExistence()) Then...`

Comment: That's not possible. You can't return result of an async process via your function. You must return a `Promise` and extract that result using `func().then()`